# Tell when the player force closes the game in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a database to communicate with Unity, which is working like a charm. Except for one problem, I was wondering when the player forces the game to close how I can call a WWW function, rather than me closing the game and being able to do it before the game closes.

Thanks,
Ethan!

Comment: I don't think so. A quick idea - when your app runs save a file with some value in it, on app quit, save a different value.
This way when your application runs again but was not closed neatly it will know about it and probably be able to do something about it.

Comment: What should be happening if the user doesn't force close but the system crashes because of a power outage? There's no chance for you to get this call out. Is this probably also a situation you should consider? Might the two issues have a single solution?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-quitting.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-wantsToQuit.html

Comment: There are too many ways user can close the game that you are not able to detect. If any of your backend components (www service, database, whatever else) depends on you knowing if user have the app turned on, you should use a different solution. I personally would use "heartbeat" pings for that, but I'm not really an expert with managing remote services